# Human name comparison: ways to approach this task

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp

I'm not a Natural Language Programming student, yet I know it's not trivial strcmp(n1,n2).

Here's what i've learned so far:

- comparing Personal Names can't be solved 100%
- there are ways to achieve certain degree of accuracy.
- the answer will be locale-specific, that's OK.

I'm not looking for spelling alternatives! The assumption is that the input's spelling is correct.

For example, all the names below can refer to the same person:

- Berry Tsakala
- Bernard Tsakala
- Berry J. Tsakala
- Tsakala, Berry

I'm trying to:

1. build (or copy) an algorithm which grades the relationship 2 input names
2. find an indexing method (for names in my database, for hash tables, etc.)

note:
My task isn't about finding names in text, but to compare 2 names. e.g.

```
name_compare( "James Brown", "Brown, James", "en-US" ) ---> 99.0%
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used Tanimoto Coefficient for a quick (but not super) solution, in Python:

```
"""
Formula:
  Na = number of set A elements
  Nb = number of set B elements
  Nc = number of common items

  T = Nc / (Na + Nb - Nc)
"""
def tanimoto(a, b):
    c = [v for v in a if v in b]
    return float(len(c)) / (len(a)+len(b)-len(c))

def name_compare(name1, name2):
    return tanimoto(name1, name2)


>>> name_compare("James Brown", "Brown, James")
0.91666666666666663
>>> name_compare("Berry Tsakala", "Bernard Tsakala")
0.75
>>>
```

**Edit:** [A link to a good and useful book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325).

Comment: tanimoto is perfectly happy taking strings, no need to list-ify them

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks.  It actually gives me a meaningful numerical result. (i'm trying to compile <a href="http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2008/06/27/computing_tanimoto_scores.html">this one</a> for all our platforms... couldn't find a binary implementation)

Comment: Berry, I'm glad I could help you :)

Comment: I see that this tanimoto function can return values > 1, is that normal?

Comment: @Stathis, the values are in the range 0...1. How did you get >1?

Comment: @NickDandoulakis tanimoto('Tsakala Berry of Persia', 'Berry Tsakala')

Comment: @Stathis, thanks. The code is indeed wrong. Quick fix: `score = min(tanimoto(a,b), tanimoto(b,a))`. The order of params matters even if they have the same length.

Comment: Thanks @NickDandoulakis. What I see is that the similarity decreases once names include middle name or father's name etc. Is there a way to tackle that?

Comment: @Stathis, name similarity is a difficult problem. You can post the question here on StackOverflow. You can also try different [textdistance algorithms](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/). Some approaches to tackle the issue, [chatgpt answer](https://chat.openai.com/share/5af63bbd-9b58-4349-9304-3c7f130dee9b)

Answer (score 1):

[Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is sometimes used to compare similar names.  It doesn't deal with first name/last name ordering, but you could probably just have your code look for the comma to solve that problem.

Comment: Yes @Jacob soundex is right thing but @berry will have to found some good implementation in the language he is using.

Comment: That's nice, and google finds many soundex libraries and online converters. However, Bernard!=Barry in Soundex.

Comment: Wrong answer.  Soundex overcomes bad spelling, not different order.
I wrote explicitly - spelling is always correct.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed the point of your post.  I see now that you're not trying to correct others' misrepresentations of a name, but correct representations of a name.

Answer (score 1):

We've just been doing this sort of work non-stop lately and the approach we've taken is to have a look-up table or alias list. If you can discount misspellings/misheard/non-english names then the difficult part is taken away. In your examples we would assume that the first word and the last word are the forename and the surname. Anything in between would be discarded (middle names, initials). Berry and Bernard would be in the alias list - and when Tsakala did not match to Berry we would flip the word order around and then get the match.

One thing you need to understand is the database/people lists you are dealing with. In the English speaking world middle names are inconsistently recorded. So you can't make or deny a match based on the middle name or middle initial. Soundex will not help you with common name aliases such as "Dick" and "Richard", "Berry" and "Bernard" and possibly "Steve" and "Stephen". In some communities it is quite common for people to live at the same address and have 2 or 3 generations living at that address with the same name. The only way you can separate them is by date of birth. Date of birth may or may not be recorded. If you have the clout then you should probably make the recording of date of birth mandatory. A lot of "people databases" either don't record date of birth or won't give them away due to privacy reasons.

Effectively people name matching is not that complicated. Its entirely based on the quality of the data supplied. What happens in practice is that a lot of records remain unmatched - and even a human looking at them can't resolve the mismatch. A human may notice name aliases not recorded in the aliases list or may be able to look up details of the person on the internet - but you can't really expect your programme to do that.

Banks, credit rating organisations and the government have a lot of detailed information about us. Previous addresses, date of birth etc. And that helps them join up names. But for us normal programmers there is no magic bullet.

Comment: Nice, although middle names play very important role in distinguishing  common names from each other. Take, for example, Spanish names: adding a single letter or middle name narrows down significantly a possible match against a list of alternative names.

Comment: I did say that if you discount non-english names. If you're working in a cultural situation where middle names were significant then you would obviously change the logic. The second name would effectively become part of the first name. In that situation I would be trying to get a match on forename, second name and surname and then try again without second name and perhaps rank the results accordingly

Comment: In English it is advisable to ignore middle name / middle initials. Middle names are inconsistently recorded and middle initials are prone to being misheard when recorded. I followed this approach matching names from differing databases. We ended up with about 20k of people records.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing name order and the existence of middle names/initials is trivial, of course, so it looks like the real challenge is knowing common name alternatives.  I doubt this can be done without using some sort of nickname lookup table.  [This list](http://deron.meranda.us/data/nicknames.txt) is a good starting point.  It doesn't map Bernard to Berry, but it would probably catch the most common cases.  Perhaps an even more exhaustive list can be found elsewhere, but I definitely think that a locale-specific lookup table is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had real problems with the Tanimoto using utf-8.

What works for languages that use diacritical signs is `difflib.SequenceMatcher()`